# If $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x f(s)ds$, is $f$ constant? Periodic?

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics, average

I was thinking of periodic functions, and in particular the following type of condition:

> If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ always "tends to its average", then it should be periodic.

To make things more formal, by "tending to the average" we could say something like $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x f(s)ds$. This is only the average depending on a previous time interval of length $1$, but it seems an interesting enough property. However, the only type of functions which I could find that satisfies this property are the constant ones!

> **Question:** If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (or more generaly measurable) and $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x f(s)ds$ for (almost) every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then is $f$ constant (a.e.)? Periodic (a.e.)?

Here is a first try for $C^1$ functions (see edit below!): If $f$ is $C^1$ and $x$ is fixed, we can use Taylor expansion $f(s)=f(x)+O(s-x)$ (and similarly for $x-1$) to obtain
\begin{align*}
f(x+t)-f(x)&=\int_x^{x+t}f(s)ds-\int_{x-1}^{x-1+t}f(s)ds\\
&=\int_x^{x+t}f(x)+O(s-x)ds-\int_{x-1}^{x-1+t}f(x-1)+O(s-x+1)ds\\
&=t(f(x)-f(x-1))+O(t^2),
\end{align*}
so $f'(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$. This is obviously true if $f$ is constant, but the converse is not clear to me at the moment.

---

**Edit**: From a comment and answer below, the equation $f'(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ has non-periodic solutions on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, so this should not be the way to go for $C^1$ functions. However, even in this case it is not clear that any solution of this equation will satisfy $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x f(s)ds$, which is the question: All I can obtain, in principle, is $f(x)-f(x-1)=\int_x^{x-1}f(s)ds-\int_{x-2}^{x-1}f(s)ds$.

Comment: This is a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). Not all solutions are constant or periodic.

Comment: Also related: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1252609p6460789

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a typical argument using characteristic equation:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ solve the equation $\alpha = 1-e^{-\alpha}$. One can indeed prove that such solution exists. One such solution is numerically given by $-2.08884 + 7.46149 i$. Then

$$ \int_{x-1}^{x} e^{\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1 - e^{-\alpha}}{\alpha} e^{\alpha x} = e^{\alpha x}, $$

hence $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$ is one (complex-valued) solution of the equation

$$ f(x) = \int_{x-1}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{*}$$

If one is interested in real-valued solutions only, then one can consider both the real part and the imaginary part of $e^{\alpha x}$. In particular, this tells that there exists an analytic solution of $\text{(*)}$ which is neither constant nor having real-period.

---

**Addendum.** We prove the following claim:

> **Claim.** There exists a non-zero solution of $\alpha = 1 - e^{-\alpha}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

*Proof.* We first note that $\varphi(x) = x(1-\log x)$ satisfies $\varphi(0^+) = 0$ and $\varphi(1) = 1$. Next, let $k$ be a positive integer. Then

1. There exists $y \in (2k\pi, (2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi)$ such that $ \varphi(\sin(y)/y) = \cos (y) $, by the intermediate-value theorem.
2. Set $x = \log(\sin(y)/y)$.

We claim that $ \alpha = x + iy $ solves the equation. Indeed, it is clear that $ e^{-x}\sin y = y $ holds. Moreover,

$$ (1-x)e^x = \varphi(\sin(y)/y) = \cos(y), $$

and so, $1 - x = e^{-x}\cos(y)$. Combining altogether,

$$ 1 - \alpha = 1 - x - iy = e^{-x}\cos(y) - ie^{-x}\sin(y) = e^{-x-iy} = e^{-\alpha}. $$

Therefore the claim follows. ////

(A careful inespection shows that this construction produces all the solutions of $\alpha = 1 - e^{-\alpha}$ in the upper half-plane.)

Comment: I think you want $\varphi(x)=x(1-\log x)$ instead. It satisfies the same properties, and $$(1-x)e^x=(1-\log(sin(y)/y))\sin(y)/y.$$
Other than that, the real part $f(t)$ of $t\mapsto e^{\alpha t}$ will be $f(t)=e^{xt}\cos(yt)$, a non-periodic solution of the original equation.

Comment: @Questioner, That's a nice catch! I will fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x)=3x^2-4x+1$  for $x\in(0,1)$ so the differential equation is true for $x=1$.
  For $x\in(1,2)$, solve the differential equation 
$$\frac{df}{dx}=f(x)-(3(x-1)^2-4(x-1)+1)$$ 
Iterate the procedure, for $x\in (2,3)$ and so on.

Comment: That's nice. However, how do we define $f(x)$ for $x<0$? Also, I have not proved yet that the equation $f'(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ implies that $f$ satisfies the property described above.

Comment: Nevermind the first part of the comment above: For $x\in[-1,0]$ we have $f'(x+1)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, so this defines $f$ on $[-1,1]$ and we iterate...

Comment: @Questioner Note that$$f(1)=\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0,$$thus integrating $f'(t)=f(t)-f(t-1)$ for $t\in[1,x]$ yields$$f(x)=\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^{x-1}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{x-1}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$$for $x\geqslant1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer where I provided some properties for $f$ that complies with
$$
f(x)=\int_{x-1}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I will update this thread as I make any further progress.

> **1.** $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ if $f\in L_{\rm loc}^1(\mathbb{R})$ ($f$ must be smooth if it is locally integrable).

*Proof.* $\forall\,x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $\forall\,x\ge x_0+1$, we have
$$
f(x)=\int_{x_0}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s-\int_{x_0}^{x-1}f(s)\,{\rm d}s.
$$
Since $f\in L_{\rm loc}^1(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that
$$
\int_{x_0}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s\quad\text{and}\quad\int_{x_0}^{x-1}f(s)\,{\rm d}s
$$
are absolutely continuous. Thus $f$ is absolutely continuous on $\left(x_0+1,\infty\right)$. The arbitrariness of $x_0$ implies that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus necessarily, $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$.

Likewise, since $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that
$$
\int_{x_0}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s\quad\text{and}\quad\int_{x_0}^{x-1}f(s)\,{\rm d}s
$$
are continuously differentiable, which leads to $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Repeat the above reasoning inductively, and we eventually obtain $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.$\#$

This conclusion suggests that, at least for a most general case, we shall only consider those $f$'s that are smooth on $\mathbb{R}$.

> **2.** $f=0$ if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ($f$ must be zero if it is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$).

*Proof.* Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, it is obvious that
$$
\int_{x-1}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{\left[0,1\right]}(x-s)f(s)\,{\rm d}s=\left(1_{\left[0,1\right]}*f\right)(x).
$$
Hence, the original relation is equivalent to the following convolution equation on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
f=1_{\left[0,1\right]}*f.
$$

Note that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is well-defined. By the convolution theorem,
$$
\hat{f}=\widehat{1_{\left[0,1\right]}}\,\hat{f}\Longrightarrow\left(1-\widehat{1_{\left[0,1\right]}}\right)\hat{f}=0.
$$
This implies that $\hat{f}=\hat{f}(\xi)=0$ for all $\xi\ne 0$. Besides, the continuity of $\hat{f}$ yields $\hat{f}(0)=0$. Consequently, we have
$$
\hat{f}=0\iff f=0.\#
$$

This conclusion suggests that any non-trivial solution to the original equation must be non-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, e.g., non-zero constants. Nevertheless, given that it is reasonable to assume $f$ to be locally integrable, the original equation can always be formulated in the convolution form $f=1_{\left[0,1\right]}*f$. Just note that $\hat{f}$ is not defined and the convolution theorem no longer applies if $f$ is locally integrable but not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

> **3.** $f\equiv\text{const}$ if $f\in L_{\rm loc}^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C_T(\mathbb{R})$ ($f$ must be constant if it is locally integrable and $T$-periodic).

*Proof.* Since $f\in L_{\rm loc}^1(\mathbb{R})$, we have $f\in C^{\infty}(\left[0,T\right])$. Thanks to the periodicity, $f$ observes its Fourier series on $\left[0,T\right]$
$$
f(x)\sim\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n\,e^{\frac{2i\pi nx}{T}}.
$$

Since $f\in C^{\infty}(\left[0,T\right])$, the Fourier series of $f$ converges absolutely and uniformly to $f$. Therefore, we have for one thing,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n\,e^{\frac{2i\pi nx}{T}}.
$$
For another,
\begin{align}
\int_{x-1}^xf(s)\,{\rm d}s&=\int_{x-1}^x\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n\,e^{\frac{2i\pi ns}{T}}{\rm d}s\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n\int_{x-1}^xe^{\frac{2i\pi ns}{T}}{\rm d}s\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n\frac{1-e^{-\theta_n}}{\theta_n}e^{\frac{2i\pi nx}{T}},
\end{align}
where $\theta_n=2i\pi n/T$, and $\left(1-e^{-\theta_0}\right)/\theta_0=1$ (this is defined so that the form of the series preserves; otherwise, one may carry out the integration separately for $n=0$ and $n\ne 0$, and may find the results identical).

Thanks to this result, the original equation requires
$$
a_n=a_n\frac{1-e^{-\theta_n}}{\theta_n}\iff\left(1-\frac{1-e^{-\theta_n}}{\theta_n}\right)a_n=0.
$$
Note that
$$
1-\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z}=0
$$
yields only one solution on $i\mathbb{R}$ (the imaginary axis), i.e., $z=0$. Thus since $\theta_n\ne 0$ for all $n\ne 0$, it is a must that $a_n=0$ for all $n\ne 0$. This leads to $f(x)=a_0$, i.e., $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.$\#$

This conclusion suggests that any continuous periodic function that satisfies the original equation must be constant.

[TBC...]

[Following @Empy2's answer, I believe the existence of some non-periodic solution to the original equation. Yet as per the above properties, this solution has to be smooth and most likely unbounded. Trying the polynomial series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ could be promising, but it leads to an infinite dimensional linear system, and its convergence also remains unknown, which challenges the commutativity of summation and integration...]

Answer (score -1):

Let
$$f(x) = \dfrac{a_0}2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(a_n\cos2\pi nx + a_n\sin2\pi nx\right),$$
then 
$$\int\limits_{x-1}^x f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac {a_0}2,$$
so $f(x)$ is a constant.