# How to solove $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x {f(t)dt}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f$ is real valued continous funtion. $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^x {f(t)dt}$, then $f$ is constant function? I prove that If there is an interval where the function value of $f$ is constant. But I
generally failed to prove.

Comment: How did you prove that there is an interval where $f$ is constant? If you mention the argument it may be possible to extend it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Supposed there is an interval where f is constant.

Comment: Oh, I see : you started by assuming it was constant in an interval, and then proved that it was constant everywhere, right? How did you get that part, then? Basically, you have done some work, and I would like to see that in some detail.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes.

Comment: Why don't you restrict yourself to $[0,2]$, and experiment with the existence of a "maximum value" of $f$ on a closed and bounded interval? It seems that such a thing could work.

Comment: There are non-constant solutions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3064768/42969.

Comment: Also related: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1252609p6460789